# Is it legal to use IntelliJ's EAP versions for commercial use?

Tags: intellij-idea

From my understanding, the EAP version has the ultimate features included in it.
I am curious whether this version can be used for commercial use.

I have no been able to find a definite answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for legal advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal advise and not about programming

Comment: It is very much related to inellij-idea, and it is not a far-fetched assumption that users of this IDE would know this information.

Comment: It would be better to ask JetBrains directly.

Comment: I asked JetBrains directly. Their exact words (I was very specific about the fact that I was using EAP): "Thank you for contacting JetBrains. You can use the license for commercial development."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. If you look at the IDEA*.txt licenses in the `<ideaInstallDir>/license` directory of an EAP version, you will see that they are exactly the same as those in the released version.  Basically EAP's are considered evaluation licenses (see comment by JetBrains [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Maia+EAP?focusedCommentId=24543568#comment-24543568)). If you (or your lawyers) want to be absolutely sure, I recommend e-mailing [sales@JetBrains.com](http://mailto:sales@JetBrains.com)

Comment: So actually, the answer is "Yes, but only with the right license" - which might be taken as "no" by the OP :-).

Comment: Like Mitch said on the comment above : "You can use the license for commercial development"