# Enabling web application support in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, vs-web-application-project

I have a Gradle Java project with embedded jetty server.
I want to enable web application support for the same project.

The Intellij IDEA help tells how to enable for an existing project in the below link.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-application-support.html#d1788100e258

But the procedure uses a ultimate edition of Intellij IDEA. I am working on Community edition. Is there a way I can manually enable the web application support on the community edition?

Can someone please provide inputs on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I did not find a way to enable web application into the Intellij Community Edition.

The reason I wanted to enable web application was to define the servlet context in the web.xml file. There is an alternate way of doing it by programmatically. I defined a ServletContextHandler and set the setInitParameter for the ServletHolder. The below link describes how to do that,

http://www.nikgrozev.org/2014/10/16/rest-with-embedded-jetty-and-jersey-in-a-single-jar-step-by-step/

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), IntelliJ Community Edition doesn't have support for Jetty

Comment: I could embed jetty by just including a dependency (compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.9.v20160517') into the build.gradle. Its up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Web development is supported only in Ultimate edition <sup>([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html))</sup>.

If you are a cheapskate use the Early Access Preview from [Jetbrain's Confluence page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/EAP).

The EAP might have bugs - but it's free, has all the features of the Ultimate edition, and then some. IntelliJ IDEA EAP is legal for commercial use <sup>([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804880/is-it-legal-to-use-intellijs-eap-versions-for-commercial-use))</sup>.